# Sharepoint managed Properties

Tags: sharepoint, search

> **Moved to Server Fault:**
>   [Sharepoint managed Properties](https://serverfault.com/questions/38858/sharepoint-managed-properties)

I have a custom Content Type inside a list that has over 30 items, and I have added several "managed properties" to the "crawled properties", in the SSP.

All of them work except 1.
The column "Synopsis" is a multiline field with no limit on it's length. It appears as a crawled property "Synopsis", and is mapped to a managed property 'asynop'.

On the 'Advanced Search Page', it is added as a property and searchable, however it only returns a partial result (if at all). I manually created an entry, ran the crawl and was able to search for it. I edited an existing entry, ran the crawl (full and incremental), and it still only returned the manually entered entry.

If I entered the search term in the Search box directly "synopsis:fatigue", then all the correct results appear.

What the is happening? And could it please stop?

Comment: Are the partial results limited to 64 characters?

Comment: I was thinking 256 chars :) If i search via 'synopsis:fatigue' then ALL the right results returned, if I used the same managed property via advacnced search, the only result was an entry I manually entered

Comment: You may want to ask this on http://serverfault.com as it's less of a programmer question, more of a server config question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is dependent on what type of search is executed.
See Steve Currans great answer to this post: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sharepointsearch/thread/f3f1d778-796e-4321-9c76-a6ede421a42f